# Problem with os.makedirs() function with Python3 on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, directory, mkdir

I'm having some trouble getting the os.makedirs() function to work. I'm currently experimenting in IDLE's shell right now and this is the error I'm getting when trying to use this function:

```
os.makedirs('/delicious\walnut\waffles')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 1, in <module>
    os.makedirs('/delicious\walnut\waffles')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/delicious\\walnut\\waffles'
```

Im just trying to create a random new directory. I'm going through this book called "Automate the Boring Stuff" and I'm doing this as part of Chapter 8.

Answer (score 1):

Its seems like the folder path you are trying to use is only available for reading, not for writing. Try changing the settings of the path.

Take a look at this:

> https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-permissions-for-files-folders-or-disks-mchlp1203/mac

Comment: But the folder path doesn't exist yet right? That's what os.makedirs() is supposed to do I think. I believe it should create those directories. If this is so, I'm not sure how I would change the permissions on the folder if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Try to change the permissions from the folder above it

Comment: have you tried adding "mode" in os.makedirs()?.mkdir (): "Creates a directory named path with numeric mode "mode". The default mode is 0777 (octal). In some systems, the mode is ignored. Where it is used, the current mask value is first masked out. Availability: Macintosh, Unix, Windows". I can direct you to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627198/python-mkdir-giving-me-wrong-permissions   to understand how it works!

Comment: Read only permissions in my case, thanks a lot